Job Prospects for a Retired University Director with a PhD in Geology
This question is for my father, a 62 yr old Retired University Director and Professor. He has a PhD in Geology from the University of Montana on a Fulbright scholarship. He taught geology for a while and then switched to an administrative position from which he retired almost 2 years ago. My father is a man who cannot sit idle at home, he likes to be productive and despite his impressive portfolio and many accomplishments, for the past 2 years he has unable to find a job or any kind of work that suits him. He is a extremely accomplished and well educated man who has been the pioneer of several educational programs in his life time.
What kind of jobs and work can he do now at this age? We live in Pakistan, so the work could preferably be remote but if there are any opportunities for him abroad then that would be great too since he has work and travel experience in many countries around the world.

welcome to this site. Sorry to hear that your father cannot get a job, but your question is individual specific and therefor off topic for this site.

My late grandfather was a mining engineer for his career. In retirement he took up archaeology as a hobby and the local university department was quite happy to have a very knowledgeable volunteer who was well practiced in surveying and proper documentation. But, that wasn't a job, but it sure kept him satisfied.

Is your father financially able to explore new areas, projects, groups, clubs?

A paid job is probably not an option. He can write books. He can volunteer. He can speak to students at a local educational institution at any level. There are hobbies. He can tutor, perhaps. Lots of things, but few are traditional employment. Hopefully his retirement is well enough funded that he doesn't need a salary.
He can attend scholarly conferences if such exist in his field. He can consult with other geologists.
If he is a member of a professional organization in the field, they may have some suggestions. He could even think about running for election to an office there.
